# How to make script rerun if a different image is in the position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that changes the middle image class on window load, how do I change the position of the next image that is in that place? It only changes the initial item. I tried adding a duplicate function right under to see if it would run.

```js
$(window).on("load", function scrolldim() {

  var xHome = window.innerWidth / 2;
  var yHome = window.innerHeight / 2;
  var pElement = document.elementFromPoint(xHome, yHome).id;

  $(".mid img").not(document.getElementById("#" + pElement))
    .fadeTo("slow", 0.3);

  if ($(".mid img").attr('id') == pElement) {
    $("#" + pElement).fadeTo("slow", 1);

  }


  function scroll2() {

 var xHome = window.innerWidth / 2;
 var yHome = window.innerHeight / 2;
 var pElement = document.elementFromPoint(xHome, yHome).id;

 if ($(".mid img").attr('id') == pElement) {
 $("#" + pElement).fadeTo("slow", 1);

 }
}
}
```

Comment: please reformat your post, it is really hard to read

Comment: Can you add some example of what is wrong in your code? Working snippet/plunker/jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: Here is a more descriptive post, same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536222/need-to-dim-images-on-sides-of-main-image-in-slider

Answer (score 0):

i think you should come more specific.for example which event will effect on next image ? what do you mean with place ? is it div or body it self ? and what is

Comment: Here is  a more descriptive post, it got no attention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536222/need-to-dim-images-on-sides-of-main-image-in-slider